# NEC 76F004GD Disassembly

Tags: ida, disassembly

I have a Toyota ECU from 2005 with an NEC 76F0004GD micro controller on it, I have already read the full 512k dump from the chip using a K-Tag. However, when I tried to put it into IDA, there weren't any options for this architecture! I checked Ghidra as well, no luck. I don't have a problem adding a new processor to IDA using the SDK, but I can't seem to find ANY information about this chip online!

Anyone have any clues?

Many thanks,

Zephurah

Answer (score 2):

The chip number is not “architecture”. You need to find out what CPU core it’s using (e.g.  V850) and look for that.

There may be hundreds or thousands of different chips using the same instruction set, it would not make sense to list them all as separate processor entries.

**EDIT**: I could find a datasheet for a NEC **µPD76F0018** which says it uses a **V850E** Family core, so I suspect yours is a V850 too (E or non-E).

Comment: Thanks! The V850 series worked.

Answer (score 1):

Toyota diesel ECU can be disassembly with Ghidra and Renesas V850 module https://github.com/esaulenka/ghidra_v850 (E850v3).

I think IDA can also disassembly Toyota Renesas V850 structure but i haven't got time to test it yeat.